# kmap for HIGHMEM

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

I use `kmap` to get logical address of page but I'm a bit confuse about high memory. If the page lies at high memory, what does `kmap` return? One source said that logical address, another - the linear address of descriptor of page.

The aim is getting directly access to physical pages' content by transforming vma addresses into linear kernel space address of certain pages.

Answer (score 1):

kmap always returns a virtual address that addresses the desired page. If the page is already accessible -- i.e. it already has a valid kernel virtual address (because, say, it's in the FIXADDR area and hence already mapped) -- then that address is simply returned to you. If it's in the highmem area, then a temporary virtual address mapping is established and a valid virtual address of the memory is returned.

The transformation referenced by your last sentence is a bit ambiguous, but since you have a "struct page" I assume you mean a page that came from a vm_struct-described mapping? ("vma" is somewhat overloaded)

In any case, assuming your real aim is just to obtain an address through which you can "directly" modify and examine a designated location in arbitrary physical memory in the case where you already have a 'struct page', kmap should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

By definition kernel logical address (also called as linear address) are virtual address in kernel space that can be translated into physical address by subtracting a fixed offset.

The range of kernel address space is a fixed compilation time parameter so if virtual address space runs from 3G - 4G (say) then low mem can run from 3G - OFFSET to 4G - OFFSET. Pages outside this range is high memory. Therefore there can be no kernel logical address for a high memory page.

kmap() creates a mapping for the high memory page into kernel address space and returns a virtual address, which can be accessed to get to the high mem page's contents.